# How to check button is clicked inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Scenerio:

I have a function:
The function `Addprocedure()` is called on `onclick` of `Addprocedure` button.
In this function i want to check if `btnAddSelectedProcedures` is clicked then do Something else do nothing

```
 function Addprocedure(){
        if()// Check if Button is clicked, button id = `btnAddSelectedProcedures`
           {
              //Do Something
           }
           else{
              //Do nothing
           }
    }
```

Comment: Define the `check button` meaning.

Comment: U have multiple buttons calling this callback ?

Comment: Why do the check if this function only gets triggered by clicking the button? Then you would check something that is always True?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$('#btnAddSelectedProcedures').click(function(){
    $(this).data('clicked', true)
})
```

then

```
function Addprocedure(){
    if($('#btnAddSelectedProcedures').data('clicked')){
        //clicked
    } else {
        //not clicked
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice logic save the data if clicked  ..thats nice ...than u

Answer (score 5):

Save the state of the button in a variable.

Define `btnClicked` globally as `false`. When `btnAddSelectedProcedures` is clicked, change `btnClicked` to `true`. When you call `Addprocedure` check if `btnClicked` variable is `true` and if so, that button has been clicked.

Example:

```
var btnClicked = false;

function Addprocedure() {
    if (btnClicked) {
        //Do something...
    } else {
        //Do something else...
    }
}

$('BUTTON[name="btnAddSelectedProcedures"]').click(function() {
    btnClicked = true;
});

$('BUTTON[name="Addprocedure"]').click(function() {
    Addprocedure();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It is simple, check id

```
function Addprocedure(){
        if(this.id === 'btnAddSelectedProcedures')// Check if Button is clicked, button id = `btnAddSelectedProcedures`
           {
              //Do Something
           }
           else{
              //Do nothing
           }
    }
```

Comment: Most simple solution...just check the id

Answer (score 1):

One possiblity,

You can  declare a `global variable`  and mark it as `true` when  your`btnAddSelectedProcedures`   clicked and  use that to check in your `Addprocedure()`  function.

```
var isButton1Clicked =false;

onButton1Click{
 isButton1Clicked ==true
}


onButton2Click{
if(isButton1Clicked){
//procedd
}
```

}

Comment: a global variable could be a bad approach, specially for a non expert user

Comment: @steo This is one possibility.But it's not evil.

Comment: When I started using jQuery/javascript and was trying script like this, global variable always messed up all my work, causing me a lot of trouble and misunderstanding. By the way, yes, is an approach,

Comment: @steo so true :) .If he start using this much simple examples ,OP might get an view,how they work.Before dealing with complex solutions.

Comment: @steo Global variables are **one of the most basic principle of programming**. If you don't understand them and you're playing with events and functions, then you shouldn't be programming.

Comment: @Jared they are a basic principle, not a good one for this kind of scripting.

Comment: I recommend using classes if you really want to do it right, but a global variable will do just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to avoid using global `var`. Use a `class` instead ( or You can set `data-*` attribute as well )

```
$('#btnAddSelectedProcedures').on('click', function(){
 //$(this).toggleClass('clicked');

 if(! $(this).hasClass('clicked') ){ //allows you to set only once the class
   $(this).addClass('clicked'); 
 }
Addprocedure();
});
```

then

```
function Addprocedure(){
    if( $("#btnAddSelectedProcedures").hasClass('clicked') ) //I guess you can call $(this) too
       {
          //Do Something
       }
       else{
          //Do nothing
       }
}
```

I used `toggleClass` because I think you want to check every time if the user clicked .
Use `addClass` in the other way.

Comment: these ensure you security. If you use global variable you'll get in a lot of trouble. I used to use gloabl variable too and I throwed really a lot of time

Comment: -1 for using classes. If you really want to save the state of the button, I would use data attributes (just like another answer suggests). Classes should be reserved for styling.

Comment: @Jared oh really lol, this is a really common solution. Also because often on clicked buttons there are different styling.

Comment: @steo Times are changing. Using data attributes is the norm these days.

Comment: Infact I use them, but if you also to apply style, you use classes. If you get offended , don't downvote others ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="1" onClick="Addprocedure(this.id)">B1</button>
```

and then

```
function Addprocedure(clicked_id)
{
    alert(clicked_id);
}
```